# Could not find or load main class Gradlew Caused by : Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: //gradlew

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, gradle, intellij-idea, build.gradle

I am new to Gradle and Selenium testing. I am working on Mac & using intelliJ .
I am trying to setup my Junit Run Configuration for running selemium test in a package.

Please refer to image 2.

Line marked with 1 has all the configurations like the chrome version, aws keys. It starts with command:  **./gradlew clean**

Line marked with 2 has the package containing Selenium test class that I need to run.

I built the project using : ./gradlew clean build testClasses -x test

Now when I try to run the Test Configuration I created , it fails with this error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class ..gradlew
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: //gradlew
Process finished with exit code 1
```

Please refer to the image 1 below for the error.

I have tried the solutions given on this link but nothing is helping:
[link](https://support.snyk.io/hc/en-us/articles/360007745957-Snyk-test-Could-not-find-or-load-main-class-org-gradle-wrapper-GradleWrapperMain)

Is the error coming because I am using **gradlew** (gradle wrapper) in command instead of **gradle**?

Update, tried the Run Config command with gradle too, still the same error, now with gradle :

```
Error: Could not find or load main class ..gradle
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: //gradle
```

Please suggest solutions to me, let me know if any other details or files are required to be shared form my end.

[image]

[image: run]

Answer (score 0):

Solved this issue- in line 1 highlighted in image 2, I removed the `/.gradlew clean` command, and just kept the environment variables like AWS keys, chrome driver details & environment type and it worked.